# Proving a metric space has sequential compactness

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology

Let

$$X:=\left\{(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}: x_n \in \mathbb{R},\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} \cdot \frac{|x_n|}{1+|x_n|} \lt \infty\right\}$$

be the metric space of sequences with the metric:

$$d(x,y) := \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} \cdot \frac{|x_n-y_n|}{1+|x_n-y_n|}$$

Prove that the unit ball entered around 0, $B_1(0):= \left\{(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}:\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} \cdot \frac{|x_n|}{1+|x_n|} \leq 1 \right\}$ is sequentially compact, and hence compact.

I don't get how it can be sequentially compact, for example the sequences $(1,1,1,\ldots), (2,2,2,\ldots) \ldots, (k,k,k,\ldots) \ldots,\forall k \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ lie inside the ball the minimum distance between any two sequences  in the set is $\frac{1}{4}$ ? Did I think about it wrongly...

Comment: $X$ contains all sequences of real numbers. The condition you have put on $(x_n)$ is automatically satisfied. In fact $B_1(0)=X$!.

Comment: The space  is just $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ in the product topology, as is well known. This is not locally compact at any point, so closed balls are certainly never compact here.

Answer (score 1):

Looks fine to me, except I'd say that the minimum distance is $\frac{1}{2}$, not $\frac{1}{4}$. Note that
\begin{align*}
d((a, a, a, \ldots), (b, b, b, \ldots)) &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n}\frac{|a - b|}{1 + |a - b|} \\
&= \frac{|a - b|}{1 + |a - b|}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} \\
&= \frac{|a - b|}{1 + |a - b|} \\
&\ge \frac{1}{1 + 1} = \frac{1}{2},
\end{align*}
with equality achieved when $|a - b| = 1$.

I agree with the conclusion. This is **not** sequentially compact. Your sequence is definitely in the unit ball around the $0$ sequence, and this shows that no subsequence can be Cauchy, let alone convergent.

Comment: Thank you for your help, appreciate it!

Comment: @Bad_at_math No problem. :-)